# How to stop multiple strokes from overlaying and adding up while Texture Painting

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, texture-painting, color

When I'm texture painting and I set the brush strength lower than 1, you can see the material under the stroke. But if draw over the same line multiple times, the shiny material gets less and less visible. How do I change it so the brush strokes don't overlay on top of each other and make the material less visible?
[image: Gold]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: How are you using your image texture that you are painting the new color on? Can you screen shot your node tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
I suggest using an image texture that is 0 alpha and then painting color into it, and plug that into a Color Mix Node fed to the Base Color of the Principled Shader. Make sure to plug the Alpha from the Image Texture Node to the Fac(tor) of the Color Mix Node, and this way no matter what, the material properties stay the same.